# How do I change the IP address of a DHCP reservation in Windows Server?

Tags: dhcp, windows-server

I am trying to change the IP address of a DHCP reservation in Windows Server but the IP address box is grayed out.

Comment: I see. What does your own research suggest? I mean, did you change anything? Do you have permission? Please provide some detail

Answer (score 8):

From experience you have to delete the reservation and re-add it.

Comment: This is true for at least Server 2003 and 2008 families. Not sure about 2012, but it wouldn't surprise me if it was still true.

Answer (score 1):

The year is 2018, and version is Windows Server 2016. At least to my knowledge there's still no way you can update a reservation via GUI. Alternatively, try using Administrative Command Line windows and do the following commands:

```
netsh Dhcp Server [\\dhcpserver01] Scope 192.168.1.0 delete reservedip 192.168.1.19 MAC-ADDRESS
netsh Dhcp Server [\\dhcpserver01] Scope 192.168.1.0 Add reservedip 192.168.1.19 MAC-ADDRESS "devicename" "comment" "DHCP"
```

Tweak with it. General a script maybe. Hope it helps.